# tracking WF using windows server appfabric

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have a wcf service that is hosted in IIS. This service launches some workflows that are dynamically loaded from the db. This is not a WF Service hosted in IIS ( no .xamlx extension).

The WCF service itself is being monitored by AppFabric monitoring, is it possible to write a custom tracking participant that logs my custom tracking data to app fabric WF tracking ?

can someone point out any resources or samples that do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here : http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2010/11/02/getting-the-most-out-of-user-events-and-windows-server-appfabric-monitoring.aspx
You can use this class : WCFUserEventProvider  ( this is present in some WCF examples from MSDN) to log your custom events for App Fabric monitoring.